# Find Xcode 4 Binary

Tags: xcode, ios5.1

I'm trying to build my little app for cydia submission ... but I can't find my actual .app. 
Under the products section in Xcode, the .app is marked in red (wich means that it doesn't exists). In my project folder, there is no folder named build or something.
How can I build my app? (Xcode 4.3.2, iOS 5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind. I found the answer: shift+cmd+2 to open the Organizer, click "projects" tab, pick your project from the left bar, then finally click the small arrow right to the "Derived Data" label to open the folder. from here just navigate to /build/products/debug-iphonesimulator and there it is.